# How to control navbar spacing?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navigation

I would like my navbar elements to not take up the width of the whole page. I've done research to try find the best way to do this but I get a load of different solutions. I would like my navbar to have space either side, but for the page to remain at the full width, whilst also having the brand on the left and the links on the right. What is the best way to handle the width  of the navbar  and the spacing of its elements?

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-lg-12 navigation">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapsed" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> 
        <span><img src="images/brand.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></span>Logo
      </a>   
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapsed">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.navbar {
  background-color: cyan;
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
}
```

Image of what i have and want:

[image]

After suggested changes:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?, Open the snippet in fullscreen mode.

I have wrapped the navbar with a `container` class

And also added `pull-right` class to `navbar-collapsed` to push the links to right.

As the the rest of the page, wrap your content inside `container-fluid`

Basically `container` class has fixed width depending on the width of browser and 
`container-fluid` takes full width of browser

```css
body {}

.navbar {
  background-color: cyan;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding:4px!important;
  float:none !important;
}

.navbar-brand img {

}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">

    <div class="col-lg-12 navigation text-left">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapsed" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <span><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" width="40" height="100" alt=""></span>Logo
      </a>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right" id="navbar-collapsed">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  Rest of page content
</div>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want, thank you. I just have one other issue now, the brand doesnt seem to be a part of the navbar? Ill upload the image as part of an edit.

Comment: That worked great, but the image seems to have a height that cannot be changed this way. The "height" in the html has no effect?

Comment: With that, increasing the size of the image makes it go outside of the navbar. What i'm trying to accomplish is being able to set the size of the brand and the whole navbar will increase with it